# separate divs with same class name from each other

Tags: javascript, html, css, django

How to separate divs with same class name from each other? I have something like this:

```
    <form role="form" id="comment-form">
      <textarea class="form-control" rows="1" placeholder="{% trans 'Write a comment...' %}" name="comment" id="comment"></textarea>
  </form>

    <form role="form" id="comment-form">
      <textarea class="form-control" rows="1" placeholder="{% trans 'Write a comment...' %}" name="comment" id="comment"></textarea>
  </form>

    <form role="form" id="comment-form">
      <textarea class="form-control" rows="1" placeholder="{% trans 'Write a comment...' %}" name="comment" id="comment"></textarea>
  </form>

    ...
```

I want to add this:

```
$("#comment").keydown(function (evt) {
    var keyCode = evt.which?evt.which:evt.keyCode;
    if (evt.ctrlKey && (keyCode == 10 || keyCode == 13)) {
      $.ajax({
        url: '/articles/comment/',
        data: $("#comment-form").serialize(),
        cache: false,
        type: 'post',
```

But on keydown only first textarea with id="comment" responds, as every element must have unice id. I tried changing them to classes, but then they would ALL respond. How could i separate this forms, from getting into each others way?

Comment: ID's are unique identifiers. don't use more than one of the same. That's like me giving an ID with the name "Ronald McDonald" to two people and telling you to shake Ronald McDonald's hand, but not the one you want, the one I want.

Comment: it's an html/id issue and you don't have `#comment-list` in the html you posted.

Comment: well, how would i do that, without giving them ids?

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the id's to classes so you aren't repeating id's, then you need to reference the relative class within each block when you target `.comment-form`, '.comment', etc.

```js
$(".comment").keydown(function (evt) {
    var keyCode = evt.which?evt.which:evt.keyCode;
    if (evt.ctrlKey && (keyCode == 10 || keyCode == 13)) {
      var $commentForm = $(this).closest(".comment-form"),
          $comment = $(this);
      $.ajax({
        url: '/articles/comment/',
        data: $commentForm.serialize(),
        cache: false,
        type: 'post',
        success: function (data) {
          /* comment-list and comment-count aren't in your html...
          $("#comment-list").html(data);
          var comment_count = $("#comment-list .comment").length; 
          $(".comment-count").text(comment_count);
          */
          $comment.val("");
          $comment.blur();
        }
      });
    }
});
```

```html
<form role="form" class="comment-form">
  <textarea class="form-control comment" rows="1" placeholder="{% trans 'Write a comment...' %}" name="comment"></textarea>
</form>

<form role="form" class="comment-form">
  <textarea class="form-control comment" rows="1" placeholder="{% trans 'Write a comment...' %}" name="comment"></textarea>
</form>

<form role="form" class="comment-form">
  <textarea class="form-control comment" rows="1" placeholder="{% trans 'Write a comment...' %}" name="comment"></textarea>
</form>
```